# Python dictionary index using string containing a period character?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I currently have a python dictionary where the keys are strings representing URLs, and the values are also string URLs.

```
@socketio.on('blacklist', namespace='/update')
def add_to_blacklist(message):
    stored_blacklist.clear()
    for key, val in message.items():
        stored_blacklist[key] = val
    lookup = {'name':'blacklist'}
    resp = patch_internal('blacklist', payload={"sites":stored_blacklist}, **lookup)
```

However there is an issue with how python is interpreting the insertions. For example:

```
stored_blacklist["example.com"] = "thankspython.edu"
```

My desired behavior is that stored_blacklist maps "example.com" to "thankspython.edu" like so:

```
{'example.com':'thankspython.edu'}
```

However, printing stored_blacklist gives me this instead:

```
{'example': {'com': 'thankspython.edu'}}
```

How could I get the desired behavior where a string with a period character in it could be read as a normal string instead of automatically creating some pseudo-JSON object?

Comment: It seems the issue is on the `message` you are receiving in `add_to_blacklist`. Could you, please, send an example of what you are sending from `javascript`?

Comment: {example.com: "thankspython.edu"}
example.com: "thankspython.edu"
__proto__: Object 

This is what gets passed in. type(message) is a dict.

print(key) nets example.com